# Reactstrap - how to change base Accordion's background color?

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

I cannot seem to find a way to change the background color of the Accordion Reactstrap component.
There is nothing about this in the [Storybook](https://reactstrap.github.io/?path=/docs/components-accordion--accordion). Note that I am asking for **Reactstrap** and **not** React Bootstrap.

I tried to add `style={{backgroundColor: "black"}}` to the `<Accordion>` tag.
I even tried the flush option to see if removing the default background, as the Storybook suggests, to try to edit the color.
I also tried to change the contents of the items inside the `AccordionHeader` tag, but it only changes the contents itself, and not the whole Header, even if I remove margin / padding.

Additionally, I attempted to use a CSS file and edit the `.accordion` class, but it seems to not affect anything.

I'm trying to use a dark-theme, and the Accordion's very bright default color is not what I want.

Note that I can change the styling for the `AccordionBody` tag, as well as the `.accordionBody` class, and it works well, but I want the Header, and/or the overall Accordion to be styled.

Can someone assist?

Comment: The docs have a Bootstrap example. If yours uses Bootstrap then you can override the Bootstrap classes using css to style the Accordion: https://reactstrap.github.io/?path=/docs/components-accordion--accordion. If it's not bootstrap, you can still override the styling with CSS, inspect the current styles to see what to override.

Comment: Have you tried to add classes by className ?

Comment: @NathanielFlick I knew Reactstrap was based on Bootstrap, but for some reason, it didn't click to me that I could just edit the Bootstrap classes itself. I was able to fix this by changing "accordion-button" class. Thanks!